# reduce not working for collections.defaultdict?

Tags: python, dictionary, reduce, defaultdict

Why is `reduce()` is not working with a `defaultdict` object in the following case:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> reduce(dict.get, [1,2], d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'get' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'NoneType'
```

The above `reduce` is equivalent to `d[1][2]`, so I expected `0`, i.e. the default return value as output but I got a `NoneType` exception instead.

If I use `d[1][2]` it works fine as shown below:

```
>>> d[1][2]
0
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict.get()` returns `None` if a key is not present, *even for a `defaultdict` object*.

That's because the *job* of `dict.get()` is to return a default value instead when a key is missing. If it didn't you'd never be able to return a *different* default (the second argument to `dict.get()`):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> d.get(1, 'default')
'default'
```

In other words, your `reduce(dict.get, ..)` function is **not** the equivalent of the `d[1][2]` expression. It is the equivalent of `d.get(1).get(2)`, which fails the exact same way:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> d.get(1).get(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Use `dict.__getitem__` instead if you want to rely on the auto-insertion behaviour:

```
>>> reduce(dict.__getitem__, [1,2], d)
0
```

The expression `d[1]` translates directly to `d.__getitem__(1)`.

Comment: Why is it correct to use dict.__getitem__  rather than defaultdict.__getitem__?

Comment: @Hammerite: you can use either; `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`.